# .fillna column if two cells are empty in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, bioinformatics

Can somebody tell me why in my for loop

```
df_all = pd.read_csv("assembly_summary.txt", delimiter='\t', index_col=0)
for row in df_all.index:
    if pd.isnull(df_all.infraspecific_name[row]) and pd.isnull(df_all.isolate[row]):
        df_all.infraspecific_name.fillna('NA', inplace=True)
        print(df_all[['infraspecific_name', 'isolate']])
```

`.fillna` fills the specified cell even when the column referred to in the second part of the if statement is not null?
 I am trying to use `.fillna` ONLY if both of the cells referred to in my if statement are null.

I also tried changing the second to last line to `df_all.infraspecific_name[row].fillna('NA', inplace=True)` Which doesn't work either.

`df_all.loc[row,['infraspecific_name']].fillna('NA', inplace=True)` corrects the problem, but then when both cells `infraspecific_name` and `isolate` ARE null, it doesn't fill the cell with 'NA'

I am not sure if my lack of understanding is in Python loops or Pandas.

The .csv file I am using can be found at ftp://ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/genomes/genbank/bacteria/assembly_summary.txt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are indexing your first col, you could use [`update`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.update.html):

```
df_all['infraspecific_name']
```

Returns a Series of only the specified column. The following will perform `.fillna` only on select (elements) rows `[where condition True]`

```
[(df_all['infraspecific_name'].isnull()) & (df_all['isolate'].isnull())].fillna('NA')
```

You can achieve all your steps in one line by combining the above and preceding it all with `update`.

```
df_all.update(df_all['infraspecific_name'][(df_all['infraspecific_name'].isnull()) & (df_all['isolate'].isnull())].fillna('NA'))
```

Number of rows changed

```
len(df_all[df_all['infraspecific_name'] == 'NA'])
1825
```

The rest of the dataframe should be intact.

Answer (score 1):

This should get you what you want

```
csvfile = 'ftp://ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/genomes/genbank/bacteria/assembly_summary.txt'
df_all = pd.read_csv(csvfile, delimiter='\t', index_col=0)
mask = df_all[['infraspecific_name', 'isolate']].isnull().all(axis=1)
df_all.loc[mask, 'infraspecific_name'] = 'NA'
```

the 3rd line uses these values `df_all[['infraspecific_name', 'isolate']]` then for each value tests for nulls `.isnull()`.  Then the last part `.all(axis=1)` is finding out if all columns in each row have Truth values in them.

The 4th line is using that mask to find the locations of the values that need changing.